# What is the WebSphere hierarchy of object types?

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

The documentation for WebSphere's wsadmin tool is pretty dire. I'm automating deployments and constantly coming across the following scripting exception:

```
WASX7129E: Cannot create objects of type "JAASAuthData" in parents of type "Node"
```

Replace `JAASAuthData` and `Node` with objects of numerous, varying types. Then show the message over and over again and you'll perhaps understand my frustration. I'm constantly guessing at what can be created in what context.

Is the hierarchy of types actually documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parents of any type can be introspected with the command `AdminConfig.parents(type)`. e.g.

```
print AdminConfig.parents('GenericJMSConnectionFactory')
> JMSProvider
```

Note that attempting to get the parent of `JAASAuthData` fails for security reasons. (But it's `Security`)